# Python script to extract emails from .text file

Tags: python, extract

I am currently attempting to run a script that extracts all the emails from a .txt file. When running the script, I get an **invalid syntax** error. Perhaps someone can help...

```
import re
in_file = open("C:\\Users\\Testing1_Emails.txt","rt")


for line in in_file:
    if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+')
        print line
```

Comment: no colon at the end of your `if` line

Comment: `re.match` expects more than 1 argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write:

```
if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',  line):
```

(add 'line'  and ':')

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Completely forgot about the ':' but had no idea about 'line'. Why is the 'line' needed, if you don't mind me asking...

Comment: do not mind. I forget these ':' myself once a  while. The command re.match needs line to know where to look for the pattern

Comment: Got it, makes sense! Would you happen know how to also print the previous 3 lines that come before the 'line' that re.match finds? Would be very helpful since it has people's names and other info that I need.

Comment: Like this: for ndx, line in enumerate(lines): if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',  line):print(lines[ndx-2], lines[ndx-1], lines[ndx]). You can get this in one line with list comprehension. But you have to look that it does not print lines[-2], lines[-1] (the last entries in your file)

Comment: I received this error _for ndx, line in enumerate(lines):
NameError: name 'lines' is not defined_. Do i have to declare 'lines' before  'for ndx' ? Here's my code in case I'm doing something else wrong... `import re
in_file = open("C:\\Users\\gabriel.garcia\\Downloads\\Testing1_Emails.txt","rt")

        
for ndx, line in enumerate(lines):
    if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line):
        print(lines[ndx-2], lines[ndx-1], lines[ndx])        
`

Comment: lines was meant as a list of strings, each element containing a line. I was not sure if you can use in_file directly for lines. Probably yes. Please try.

Comment: `for ndx, line in enumerate(in_file):
    if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line):
        print(in_file[ndx-2], in_file[ndx-1], in_file[ndx]) `   like this? If so, i get a _TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable_

Comment: hm, this indexing seems making it complex. then better store the old lines like (hope it is readable): line_old, line_very_old = str(), str()
for line in in_file:
    if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line):
        print("{} {} {}".format(line, line_old, line_very_old))
    line_very_old = line_old
    line_old = line

Comment: Worked like a charm! Truly appreciate all your help, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies here:

```
for line in in_file:
    if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+')
        print line
```

In the `if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+')` statement, you don't end with `:`

Answer (score 0):

match method requires 2 arguments.

see at :  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)

If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.

If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead (see also search() vs. match()).

Answer (score 0):

most mail IDs allow alphabets, numbers, dot(.), underscores(_) and all of them contain "@" for sure. we can use this information to write a pattern using regex.

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+@[a-zA-Z\.]') # regex pattern
```

[a-z]+ will match any lower case alphabet, any number of occurence 
[0-9]+ will match any digit, any number of occurence 
[.] will match '.'

Further, if you want to check that your pattern matches your search strings, check it out here. https://regexr.com/

example:--

```
f = open("my_file.txt", "w")
f.write('walkup@cs.washington.edu, geb@cs.pitt.edu, walkup@cs.washington.edu \n')
mails = re.findall(r"[a-z]+@[a-z\.]+", f.read())
print(list(set(mails)))
```

out: ['walkup@cs.washington.edu', 'geb@cs.pitt.edu', 'walkup@cs.washington.edu']

note: re.findall() applies re.pattern() internally over the specified pattern.